# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Node not found after creating NodeJS instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, node.js, elastic-beanstalk

Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk I chose to launch an instance that runs NodeJS.  EC2 instance launched but when I check what version of node is running I get this:

`node --version`

`-bash: node: command not found`

My EC2 instance AMI ID
`aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2015.09.2.x86_64-nodejs-pv-201602232224 (ami-ae3fddce)`

Answer (score 4):

The AMI image by default doesn't add node to the bash PATH.

You can add a symlink in /bin, pointing at node using the following bash command.

```
sudo ln -sf `ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin/node /bin/node
```